# Using <script src="@microsoft/" Issue in cshtml/razor

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

Issue using an @ sign in src path of a script reference.

I am using a .cshtml page so @ is a code reference. Normally @@ will cancel out the @ sign so it will read it as a string but it doesn't seem to work in the following example.

```
<script>
    var signalrPath = "~/lib/@@microsoft/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js";
</script>

<script src="~/lib/@@microsoft/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script>
```

This translates to the following:

[image]

Is there any easy way to avoid this?

I can make a cshtml string object and insert it in to there but that seems unnecessary.

```
@{ 
    string signalR = "@microsoft";
}

<script src="~/lib/@signalR/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an explicit Razor expression:

```
<script>
    var signalrPath = "@("~/lib/@microsoft/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js")";
</script>

<script src="@("~/lib/@microsoft/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js")"></script>
```

Or, I suppose you can just do the `@microsoft` part, but I personally prefer keeping the whole string together:

```
<script src="~/lib/@("@microsoft")/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script>
```